# Get the are covered by tkinter canvas polygon

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, coordinates

I'm wondering how can I get the area (or select objects) covered by a tkinter canvas polygon?
I have made an input, where the user can draw an area (by putting its anchor points), and I would like get that area and form to know what is inside and outside of it.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what have you done so far?

Comment: Google "python area of polygon". It doesn't matter if you're using tkinter as long as you know the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: I just made a canvas, where the user can put anchor points, and the program draws a polygon with them. So I want to draw something else, with the same size and form.

Comment: You can get all polygon points and calculate if other point is inside this area but it can be not so easy to calculate it. Probably you had to split polygon into triangles and then check point with every triangle.

Comment: if you want to check if you click inside polygon then you can try to `bind()` to polygon mouse click event `<Button1>`.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the points (I don't needevery pixel, only a few points), but it's hard, so I asked if there is a simpler way.